# How do I create an anchor in a table cell in Asciiidoctor?

Tags: asciidoctor

I tried specifying

```
 a | [#abc] My Text
```

for the table cell contents but it doesn't work. It renders `[#abc] MyText` as the contents of my cell.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a few different ways:

```
|===
|Some|Value

|First|[[anchor-1]] My anchor1
|Second
|anchor:anchor-2[] anchor2
|Third
|
[[anchor-3]] anchor3
|Fourth
|
anchor:anchor-4[] anchor4

|===
```

And then you can refer to the anchors using `<<anchor-1, Link to anchor 1>>`.

Comment: Using [[anchor]] text didn't work. FYI: I'm generating the ascidoc to html via the java api for asciidoc. I don't know if the java api/jar uses an older version of asciidoctor.

Comment: So none of these work?  I'm using the maven asciidoctor plugin which I believe uses the java api underneath.  Might be worth a check to see if there's a difference in the handling.